Cubit state copyWith not emmiting
I'm trying to emmit a copy state, but widget BlocBuilder never update state.
This is my Widget build witch never update when emmit(state.copyWith()):
BlocBuilder<CouponsCubit, CouponsState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) => true,
  bloc: couponsCubit,
  builder: (context, state) =>
  _buildBodyFiltersPage(state),
)

This is the method in my CubitBloc called from my filter button:
void toggleFilter(FilterModel filter) {
  if (_filters.contains(filter)) {
  _filters.remove(filter);
  } else {
  _filters.add(filter);
  }
  
  emit(state.copyWith(filters: [..._filters]));
}

This is my Cubit state:
class CouponsState extends Equatable {
  final List<CCouponCardType> filters;

  const CouponsState._({this.filters = const []});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [filters];

  CouponsState copyWith({
    List<CCouponCardType>? filters,
  }) =>
      CouponsState._(
        filters: filters ?? this.filters,
      );
}

class EmptyState extends CouponsState {
  const EmptyState({
    super.filters,
  }) : super._();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [filters];
}

class LoadingState extends CouponsState {
  const LoadingState({
    super.filters,
  }) : super._();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [filters];
}

class LoadedState extends CouponsState {
  final CCouponListAdapter couponsList;

  const LoadedState({
    required this.couponsList,
    super.filters,
  }) : super._();

  @override
  LoadedState copyWith({
    List<CCouponCardType>? filters,
  }) => LoadedState(
    couponsList: couponsList ?? this.couponsList,
    filters: filters ?? this.filters,
  );

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [couponsList, filters];
}

class ErrorState extends CouponsState {
  final String errorMessage = noLoadCouponsString;

  const ErrorState({
    super.filters,
  }) : super._();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [errorMessage, filterString, filters, sort];
}

What I'm missing?

Can you provide more code of your BlocProvider and your Button widget ?

It seems to me that you have two different filters in your cubit. I assume _filters is some sort of variable in your cubit but you want to read filters from your state. I suggest changing your code in toggleFilter to check in state.filters instead of _filters. Then make sure that in your body you retrieve your value from the state. Also BlocBuilder depends on BlocProvider of a bloc you specified in bloc: couponsCubit, so it shouldn’t be in the same widget. If your bloc isn’t a singleton it would emit a blank state if you for example call setState on a widget that has BlocProvider. Hope that helps!
